# how to flatten lists while leaving some nesting (in python)

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list of lists of lists with strings, something like this (representing chapters, paragraphs and sentences of a text)):

```
[ [[ ['chp1p1s1'], ['chp1p1s2'], ['chp1p1s3'] ],
   [ ['chp1p2s1'], ['chp1p2s2'], ['chp1p2s3'] ]],
  [[ ['chp2p1s1'], ['chp2p1s2'], ['chp2p1s3'] ],
   [ ['chp2p2s1'], ['chp2p2s2'], ['chp2p2s3'] ]] ]
```

I know how to flatten this list completly (for example by `[x for y in z for x in y]`), but what I would like to do is to flatten it partially, to finally look like this:

```
[ [ ['chp1p1s1'], ['chp1p1s2'], ['chp1p1s3'],
    ['chp1p2s1'], ['chp1p2s2'], ['chp1p2s3'] ],
  [ ['chp2p1s1'], ['chp2p1s2'], ['chp2p1s3'],
    ['chp2p2s1'], ['chp2p2s2'], ['chp2p2s3'] ] ]
```

I managed to solve this by some for loops:

```
semiflattend_list=list()
for chapter in chapters:
    senlist=list()
    for paragraph in chapter:
        for sentences in paragraph:
            senlist.append(sentences)
    semiflattend_list.append(senlist)
```

But I wonder if there is a better, shorter solution? (I don't think, `zip` is a way to go, because my lists are different in size.)

Comment: The examples you gave is actually a tuple of two different lists, which I don't think is what you meant. You are messing up the parentheses or a comma, maybe, but we need a reporducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change I can see is using the `itertools.chain` method:

```
q = [
     [[ ['chp1p1s1'], ['chp1p1s2'], ['chp1p1s3'] ],
       [ ['chp1p2s1'], ['chp1p2s2'], ['chp1p2s3'] ]],
     [[ ['chp2p1s1'], ['chp2p1s2'], ['chp2p1s3'] ],
       [ ['chp2p2s1'], ['chp2p2s2'], ['chp2p2s3'] ]]
    ]

r = [list(itertools.chain(*g)) for g in q]
print(r)

[[['chp1p1s1'], ['chp1p1s2'], ['chp1p1s3'], ['chp1p2s1'], ['chp1p2s2'], ['chp1p2s3']],
 [['chp2p1s1'], ['chp2p1s2'], ['chp2p1s3'], ['chp2p2s1'], ['chp2p2s2'], ['chp2p2s3']]]
```

So, what does `[list(itertools.chain(*g)) for g in q]` mean:

```
# If I only had this
[g for g in q]
# I would get the same I started with.
# What I really want is to expand the nested lists

# * before an iterable (basically) converts the iterable into its parts.
func foo(bar, baz):
   print( bar + " " + baz )

lst = ["cat", "dog"]
foo(*lst) # prints "cat dog"

# itertools.chain accepts an arbitrary number of lists, and then outputs 
# a generator of the results:
c = itertools.chain([1],[2])
# c is now <itertools.chain object at 0x10e1fce10>
# You don't want an generator though, you want a list. Calling `list` converts that:
o = list( c )
# o is now [1,2]
# Now, together:
myList = [[2],[3]]
flattened = list(itertools.chain(*myList))
# flattened is now [2,3]
```

Comment: This actually solved it! Could you maybe please explain this asterisk/splat operator? In the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) it doesn't explain to me how this could help here.